# FitBit API integration IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, fitbit

I am using FitBit API to get Activities. In response I am getting a JSON array of activities. For each activity they provides some details like name, activityId, calories,etc but date and time is not available. Is there any API to get activity details along with start date and time.

Comment: This given link has sample code with fitbit framework
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34393507/fitbit-framework-is-available/34393522#34393522

Comment: This below link has sample code with fitbit framework [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34393507/fitbit-framework-is-available/34393522#34393522

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Check the [fitbit api docs](https://wiki.fitbit.com/display/API/API-Get-Activities), there is a clearly marked attribute called `startTime`.

Comment: Exactly. But the problem with that API is date. It only gives activities done on a specific date provided in URL. I am looking for an API that provides list of all activities performed along with the detail, may be between a specific range of date will work for me. Or any API that gives details of an activity for given activity ID.

Comment: @Suresh did you ever figure out how to do this? The recent activities endpoint still does not return a date. And the get activities endpoint still does not allow date range or lookup by activity id.

Comment: @BillRollins, I Can understand what problem you may be facing. To overcome this problem, I simply fetched TimeSeries for activities steps and on the basis of that I decide for which date I should fetch activities. For Example: 1. Fetch time-series for steps and store them. For very first time store all. 2. From every next sync, Again fetch time-series for steps and compare with earlier ones. Then for every those records for which steps are greater, Call activities  API with that date.

Answer (score 9):

Please call this service  https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/[user-id]/activities/date/[date].json

You will get start time and duration example

```
{
        "description" : "Very Leisurely - under 10 mph",
        "category" : "activity",
        "name" : "Bike",
        "calories" : 1000,
        "id" : "572c571610b47a37753055c6",
        "activityType" : "Bike",
        "userId" : "5722f36110b47af433f111c9",
        "deviceName" : "Fitbit",
        "duration" : 1200,
        "distance" : 1.5,
        "startDate" : "2016-05-06",
        "startTime" : "12:40",
        "steps" : 0
      }
```

For step by step tutorial and source code , you should go https://appengineer.in/2016/04/30/fitbit-aouth-in-ios-app/

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is, unfortunately, the time series that Suresh mentioned. It's a little bit of a pain because you have to grab each individual stat's time series and piece them together (please correct me if there's another way, but I didn't find one).

Comment: It's fine to turn someone's comment into an answer, but you should quote the text of the comment (or better yet, restate it in your own words) rather than just refer to it.